# Can we publish Power Apps Portal to App Source like Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, appsource, powerapps-portal

Do we have a functionality to publish Power Apps Portals on Microsoft's App Source?

Posting this rather very simple question here since I am unable to find any concrete resource stating if it is possible to publish power app portals to app source like we normally do with canvas or model-driven power apps.

Comment: Not today, but maybe in future - yes

Answer (score 0):

it's been more than a month and new updates are released:
Based on this article. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/user/app-source

> "The apps you build and publish with Power Apps are discovered and
>   used in Dynamics 365 on the web. It displays all of your apps -- the
>   apps that you've specifically chosen to use (that is, by launching
>   from a share email or opening from AppSource) or that an admin has
>   provisioned for you. This includes all of your apps from Power Apps,
>   as well as Dynamics 365 applications from Microsoft. You can search
>   for apps, filter by environment, and pin the apps you use most
>   frequently to the top of the page."
>   [image]